# P2 Touchpoint chmod not working?

Tags: eclipse, p2

I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2 and I've created a p2.inf with the following information:

```
instructions.install = \
chmod(targetDir:@artifact,targetFile:$os$/libfoo.so,permissions:755);

instructions.install.import= \
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.chmod
```

I placed the p2.inf inside the META-INF folder of the fragment, but when I install the update site, libfoo.so does not have execute permissions.

After pulling my hair out, I tried a p2.inf referencing a non-existing *.so, but nothing seems to happen. No error messages, exceptions, or warnings of any kind to indicate the P2 touchpoint action failed...

What's the deal? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The import line should be `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.chmod` (i.e. *eclipse* rather than *natives*), according to the following comment from [org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.ChmodAction](http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.p2.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse/src/org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/touchpoint/eclipse/actions/ChmodAction.java?h=R3_6_maintenance)

```
// This basically a copy of the chmod action in the native touchpoint,
// only it provides @artifact support.
```

(For comparison, see the ['natives' chmod action](http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.p2.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives/src/org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/touchpoint/natives/actions/ChmodAction.java?h=R3_6_maintenance))

I haven't checked about support for interpolating variables like 'os'.

Comment: I know this question is a year old. I've just added this answer so I can find it again. :)

Comment: Good! To day a year later I also needed to find it!

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse 3.6 (don't know about previous versions), the variable to use instead of @artifact is ${artifact.location}.  I had to dig into the p2 source code to find it, but using it in the targetDir parameter worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things I notice:

1. The "touchpoint.natives.chmod" action does not look like it supports `@artifact`.  Try using `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.chmod` instead.
2. `os` does not appear to be a parameter that is replaced at install time.  Also, looking at the p2 source code, if "os" was a parameter, it seems the syntax would actually be `${os}`.  (See ParameterizedProvisioningAction#processVariables)

Note that the `$version$` and `$qualifier$' parameters mentioned on the [wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Customizing_Metadata) are replaced at metadata generation/publishing time, not at install time.

Comment: I can't find org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.chmod in their documentation...?