# Launch External Tools from Eclipse Plug-in View

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm building a simple Eclipse plug-in out of preexisting Java application project that **relays on** 2 external files, one **x-executable/application** **and one .sh script.** 
The call is implemented in application like this, (which wouldn't work in plug-in):

```java
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("external/application_name", "-d", path).start();
```

I used **External Tool Configuration** to define how I want this external files to be launch (when user clicks button on View) and I've exported configuration (example of one):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ProgramLaunchConfigurationType">
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_LOCATION" value="${workspace_loc:/softwareevolution/external/application_name}"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TOOL_ARGUMENTS" value="-d ${project_loc}"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="${project_loc}"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

1. How can I have this application install along with Eclipse plug in,
   or a as a part of it? (see @howlger answer billow) - **I set plugin to install as directory /
   Connected plugin to Feature project- checked unpack after
   installation -  and exported Feature project**. Select application's
   folder on **Build/Binary build**.
2. Can I then make use out of this exported **.launch** files, and if so
   under which extension point should I include them in plugin.xml? -
   **No.** (see @greg-449)
3. The **application is supposed to produce** 2 **files** on the path where it
   is executed from. **I am facing permission denied** when trying to
   launch it in terminal from plug-in's install directory but not when
   launching in workspace. (see @howlger answer billow) - **Upon exporting the plugin, initial
   permissions of application had changed. Used instructions in p2.inf
   to chmod them back.**
4. The **newly generated files** (from runing .sh script) are **missing write permission**.

### ProcessBuilder

> After finally setting up plugin correctly and adding ProcessBuilder I was getting exception message : Cannot run program "rfind_20" (in
>   directory 
>   "home/adminuser/.p2/pool/plugins/rFindTest3_1.0.0.201809030453/external"
>   error=2:, No such file or directory

File rfind_20 did exist and permission were 777. The targeted project also existed.

> **Although the working directory was set to applications folder, the application name was not enough, the absolute path was required as
>   *command* argument.**

```java
pb = new ProcessBuilder(url.getPath(), "-d", project.getProject().getLocation().toString());
```

```java
@Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {


        IProject project= sampleGetSelectedProject();

        ProcessBuilder pb;
        Process rfind, ajust, copy;

        Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());//Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("rFindTest3");

        URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("external/rfind_20"), null);
        URL dirurl = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("external/"), null);



        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);

        try {

            MessageDialog.openInformation(
                    window.getShell(),
                    "Test",
                    project.getProject().getLocation().toString());

            url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url); 
            dirurl = FileLocator.toFileURL(dirurl);
            pb = new ProcessBuilder(url.getPath(), "-d", project.getProject().getLocation().toString()); 
    //no matter the working directory the absolute path was required!! sending "rfind_20" as command did not work as command
            pb.directory(new File(dirurl.getFile()));

            rfind = pb.start(); 
            rfind.waitFor();
            rfind.destroy();

        }catch(Exception e) {

            MessageDialog.openInformation(
                    window.getShell(),
                    "Test",
                    e.getMessage());

        }


    return null;

}
```

The only remaining mystery is why my sampleGetProject() method wouldn't work in Plug-in Perspective. So just **keep in mind to switch to other Perspectives when testing your plug-in**.

Comment: "which wouldn't work in plug-in" Why do you say that?

Comment: To run an executable that is contained in the plug-in, either the plug-in is installed as a directory instead of as a JAR (`Eclipse-BundleShape: dir` in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`) or the executable has to be extracted before running it.

Comment: @nitind After making plugin install as directory I am now trying ProcessBuilder again, without success, I noticed that after installing plugin I can no longer run the application from terminal, it's permissions had changed. I will look into it more tomorrow. Testing this is just too exhausting.

Comment: @howlger Plugin now installs as directory, I faced this problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079566/eclipse-bundleshape-dir-header-is-not-working-and-still-the-plugins-are-expor) and the second answer solved it.

Comment: Please upvote the answer you linked to if it helped you. I added an answer which also contains how to change file permissions via `p2.inf`.

Comment: @howger I did, but my upvotes still don't count. I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to ship an application **as part of a plugin** and run it via **`ProcessBuilder`** (the `*.launch` file cannot be used inside a plugin for that):

- **Extract** the executable files from the **plugin JAR** to a (temp) directory and **change** their **file permissions** before running them
- Install the **plugin as a directory**:

  - In **`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`** add the line **`Eclipse-BundleShape: dir`** (see *"The Eclipse-BundleShape Header"* in [Eclipse help - Platform Plug-in Developer Guide - OSGi Bundle Manifest Headers](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/bundle_manifest.html))
  - Create a **Feature Project** and connect your plug-in in Included Plug-in, check "**Unpack the plug-in archive after the installation**"
  - Create a **`META-INF/p2.inf`** file that contains the following (see Eclipse help - Platform Plug-in Developer Guide: *"Touchpoint Instruction Advice"* in [Customizing p2 metadata](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_customizing_metadata.html) and *"chmod"* in [Provisioning Actions and Touchpoints](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_actions_touchpoints.html)):

```
instructions.install = \
   chmod(targetDir:${artifact.location},targetFile:path/to/executable1,permissions:755);\
   chmod(targetDir:${artifact.location},targetFile:path/to-executale_which_generates_files/executable2,permissions:733);\
   chmod(targetDir:${artifact.location},targetFile:path/to-executale_which_generates_files/,permissions:766);
instructions.install.import = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.chmod
```

Comment: I encountered few more [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580080/p2-touchpoint-chmod-not-working) and possibly a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=304669)- restarting Eclipse after (each) failed installation helps.

Comment: @howlgler Now I am getting "An error occurred while installing the items ... "The action chmod failed - file /home/adminuser/.p2/pool/plugins/rFindTest2_1.0.0.201809021620.jar/external/rfind_20 does not exist". I checked the folder, the .jar does exist but chmod can't be preformed on file within jar. It seams to me these instructions are preformed while `tatgetFile` is (still) a .jar (Maybe it is meant to decompresses later on in installation process -because Eclipse-BundleShape is still set to dir).

Comment: @BanAnanas Does `instructions.configure` instead of `instructions.install` work?

Comment: No `An error occurred while configuring the installed items
session context was:(profile=_home_adminuser_eclipse_committers-photon_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Configure, operand=null --> [R]rFindTest2 1.0.0.201809021700, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.ChmodAction).
The action chmod failed - file /home/adminuser/.p2/pool/plugins/rFindTest2_1.0.0.201809021700.jar/external/rfind_20 does not exist`. Maybe it is up to Eclipse 'Install to the host' option? Should I try to install the plug-in some other way?

Comment: Yes, maybe this happens only when 'Install to the host'. Eclipse does the same: https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.hpux.ia64/META-INF/p2.inf?id=b05d334a701d74753767a7da8aad846d23177eca

Comment: I tried unconfigure phase just to see if having p2.inf file leads to plugin being installed as .jar (the installation finished and i was left with .jar), now this version won't uninstall because of the chmod error. I changed the plug-in id to avoid further complications. (I also run Organize manifest wizard- it had no impact.) I'm experimenting with installing it as a feature, I'd like to avoid manually putting jar in dropin folder or elsewhere)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `xxx.launch` file in the workspace you can launch it using

```java
IFile file = ... get IFile for workspace file

ILaunchConfiguration config = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunchConfiguration(file);

DebugUITools.launch(config, ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, false);
```

If you have an executable as part of a plug-in then you can't use a .launch file. Instead use `FileLocator` to get the location of the executable and run it with `ProcessBuilder`

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("relative path to executable"));

url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

Comment: I think `value="${workspace_loc:/softwareevolution/external/application_name}"` gave the impression application would be located in a Runtime Workspace, but I actually want it to be a part of a plug-in install directory/jar.

Comment: In which case you can't use a .launch file - use `FileLocator` and `ProcessBuilder` - see updated answer.

Comment: [Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068876/run-program-exe-from-eclipse-plugin-project)From class file:toFileURL Converts a URL that uses a user-defined protocol into a URL that uses the file protocol. The contents of the URL **may** be extracted into a cache on the file-system in order to get a file URL. If the protocol for the given URL is not recognized by this converter, the original URL is returned as-is. This functions might fail to place a file to a temporary location? I think my problem now is up to FileLocator. I will put code and error up soon, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You probably need to specify the full path of the executable on the ProcessBuilder constructor rather than just the name.

Comment: That did the thing, it only took me so long because since today **plug-in stopped working in plug-in perspective**  in which was testing it in. I'll look into that some other time. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: As my script generates files, which I need write access for, I'd like to define all files (to be generated) with certain extension (perhaps only within folder external) to have write permission. Do you know where I could define that? I've looked for the answer, but as I am new to this It's hard for me to know what exactly to look for (ant scripts, build.properties, p2.inf...)